# get audio device GUID in Python

Tags: python, audio, operating-system, registry, guid

I am trying to get GUID of audio device. The GUID can be found in registry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\` the guid should look like `{0.0.0.00000000}.{37e73048-025a-47ea-bf9f-59d5ef8f2b43}`

basically like this. but I want in python [Getting GUID of audio output device (speaker,headphones)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538787/getting-guid-of-audio-output-device-speaker-headphones/35540701#35540701)

I've tried myself but only thing I can find is to use command line and parse it in Python

```py
import subprocess

sd = subprocess.run(
    ["pnputil", "/enum-devices", "/connected", "/class", "AudioEndpoint"],
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)

output = sd.stdout.split("\n")[1:-1]

def getDevices(devices):
    deviceList = {}
    for device in range(len(devices)):
        if "Instance ID:" in devices[device]:
            deviceList[devices[device+1].split(":")[-1].strip()] = devices[device].split("\\")[-1].strip()
    return deviceList

print(getDevices(output))
```

which got me

```
{'Headset (Soundcore Life Q30 Hands-Free)': '{0.0.0.00000000}.{4ac89ef7-f00d-4069-b96b-421bd3276295}', 'Speakers (Echo Dot-BQP)': '{0.0.0.00000000}.{8085b216-297a-4d02-bc3d-83b997b79524}', 'Headphones (Soundcore Life Q30)': '{0.0.0.00000000}.{37e73048-025a-47ea-bf9f-59d5ef8f2b43}'}
```

Hopping there is better way

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import comtypes
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IMMDeviceEnumerator, EDataFlow, DEVICE_STATE
from pycaw.constants import CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator

def MyGetAudioDevices(direction="in", State = DEVICE_STATE.ACTIVE.value):
    devices = []
    # for all use EDataFlow.eAll.value
    if direction == "in":
        Flow = EDataFlow.eCapture.value     # 1
    else:
        Flow = EDataFlow.eRender.value      # 0
    
    deviceEnumerator = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
        IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)
    if deviceEnumerator is None:
        return devices
    

    collection = deviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(Flow, State)
    if collection is None:
        return devices

    count = collection.GetCount()
    for i in range(count):
        dev = collection.Item(i)
        if dev is not None:
            if not ": None" in str(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev)):
                devices.append(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev))
    return devices

output_device = MyGetAudioDevices("out")
input_device = MyGetAudioDevices("in")

print(output_device)
print(input_device)
```

This worked for me

Comment: Which pycaw version do you use? I installed pycaw via pip, but I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaw.constants'"